# How do I dereference Data::Dumper output?

Tags: perl

I always forget how to do this.
I have this Perl code:

print Dumper($obj);

Here is my Data::Dumper output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'classname' => 'Template',
          'oid' => 2,
          'pid' => '50'
        };
```

But when I do something like ...

```
print LOGGER "classname is [\n". $obj{'classname'} . "]\n";
```

... I get this error ...

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have used `$obj->{'classname'}`.  Without the arrow, `$obj{'classname'}` accesses the `%obj` hash instead of the hashref in `$obj`.

This is the sort of error that gets caught by `use strict;` so your real error is not doing that.

Comment: Thanks! I always get `$o->thing`, `$o{'thing'}` and `$o->{'thing'}` mixed up.